# RoR permitting non model parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, strong-parameters, mass-assignment

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to permit non model parameters.

I've read:

- [Rails Strong Parameters: How to accept both model and non-model attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703770/rails-strong-parameters-how-to-accept-both-model-and-non-model-attributes)
- [Rails 4 Strong parameters : permit all attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033908/rails-4-strong-parameters-permit-all-attributes?rq=1)
- [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

So, for a "normal" situation - let's say that I have a model `Foo` which has just one attribute `bar`:

```
# foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # bar, which is a integer
end

# views/foos/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :bar %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#foos_controller.rb
def create
    @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
    # ...
end

#...

private

def foo_params
    params.require(:foo).permit(:bar)
end
```

So, when I submit the form, the `Foo` will be created.

---

However, what if the `bar` attribute has some logic behind it that combines some non model parameters? Let's say that `bar` is the sum of two parameters (`bar = bar_1 + bar_2`). Then the view and controller looks like:

```
# views/foos/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :bar_1 %>
    <%= f.number_field :bar_2 %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#foos_controller.rb
def create
  bar_1 = params[:foo][:bar_1]
  bar_2 = params[:foo][:bar_2]

  if bar_1.present? && bar_2.present?
    @foo = Foo.new
    @foo.bar = bar_1.to_i + bar_2.to_i

    if @foo.save
      # redirect with success message
    else
      # render :new
    end
  else
    # not present
  end
end
```

So the question is, do I also need to permit the `bar_1` and `bar_2` parameters? If I do, how do I permit them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Option:** put the logic in your model:

Permit `bar1` and `bar2`:

```
def foo_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:bar1, :bar2)
end
```

Then handle this logic in your model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :bar1, bar2

  after_initialize :set_bar

  def set_bar
    self.bar = bar1 + bar2 if bar_1 && bar_2
  end
end
```

**Second Option:** Create a formatted_params method:

```
# views/foos/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :bar_1 %>
    <%= f.number_field :bar_2 %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#foos_controller.rb
def create
    @foo = Foo.new(formatted_params)

    if @foo.save
      # redirect with success message
    else
      # render :new
    end
end

def permitted_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:bar_1, :bar2)
end

def formatted_params
  bar1 = permitted_params.delete(:bar1)
  bar2 = permitted_params.delete(:bar2)
  permitted_params.merge(bar: bar1 + bar2)
end
```

Comment: In the first option, If I don't use `foo_params` for the create/update, is the method then really needed?

Comment: Yes. You would continue to do `Foo.new(foo_params)`.

Comment: Think I got it. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access those two non-model parameter, you have to bind it with model by below code on your `Foo` model

```
attr_accessor :bar_1, :bar_2
```

No need to permit it in

```
def foo_params
   params.require(:foo).permit(:bar)
end
```

Note: Make sure you remove it from your `params`, It will not raise any error, but give you a warning on `rails console` like `Unpermitted parameters: bar_1, bar_2`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to permit bar_1  and bar_2 parameters unless you create them under foo. But in your case you are creating in under foo. The best solution is to create `attr_accessor`

```
# foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # bar, which is a integer
  attr_accessor :bar_1, bar_2
end

# views/foos/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :bar_1 %>
    <%= f.number_field :bar_2 %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#foos_controller.rb
def create
  bar_1 = params[:foo][:bar_1]
  bar_2 = params[:foo][:bar_2]

  if bar_1.present? && bar_2.present?
    @foo = Foo.new
    @foo.bar = bar_1.to_i + bar_2.to_i

    if @foo.save
      # redirect with success message
    else
      # render :new
    end
  else
    # not present
  end
end
```